# Tracking facebook like button (edge.create deprecated). Is there an alternative, but without Webhooks?

Tags: facebook

I have found many answers on the question about deprecated edge.create, but it always finishes with Webhooks alternative.

Is there any other functionality/workaround how to track Facebook's like button on my site and get statistic on HEAP for all likes?

Comment: statistics? how about app insights, maybe you can find statistics in there?

Comment: @luschn Do you mean Facebook's insights? Like btn is on my site as an iframe.

Comment: yes, i mean app insights, since you need to add an app id with the like button.

Comment: @luschn ok, but is there deprecated edge.create event? I see the deprecated alert for the events on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/app_insights/
So, the alert is saying that I should use facebook analytics, but again there is a problem because custom event should be fired after click and click is on iframe. Here is the link for facebook analytics custom event: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/implementation/conversion-tracking#custom-events

Comment: i am not sure what you mean, did you check out the app insights already? it is just a guess, and edge.create is indeed deprecated. there is no alternative.

Comment: @luschn I updated the previous comment with more details. Yeah, I checked app insights if we talk about the same thing (the first link from the previous comment)

Comment: i am not talking at all about custom events, i only meant that you could checkout insights for stuff that comes from facebook directly. maybe they do track like button stats already. if they don´t, then there is no way. of course you cannot check for the click on your own.

Comment: and i mean the insights you get directly in  your app settings. the automatic ones from facebook.

Comment: @luschn I'll check those insights. Thanks for your help :)